# Populate a textbox with mysql data after a combobox selection

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, combobox, textbox

So I have 2 mysql tables, one called "Service_Details" and one called "Payment_details"

I have a combobox in my form which displays the "service_id" field from the service table.
I'm trying to code a textbox, so when I select the service id from the combobox it writes the "service" which is another field in my service details table. The service id is linked to a service.

I am getting errors 'identifier expected' at [0] and 'Value of type 'system.data.datatablecollection' cannot be converted to 'string' at dss.tables

I can't seem to get it working after browsing the internet for an hour

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub cbxserviceid_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbxserviceid.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dss As New DataSet
    Dim daa As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from service_details WHERE ServiceID='" + cbxserviceid.Text + "'", objconnection)
    Dim cmddd = New MySqlCommandBuilder(daa)
    daa.Fill(dss)
    txtService1.Text = dss.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Service"].ToString();
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The indexes in VB.NET are expressed using the round braces, the square brackets are used in C#

```
txtService1.Text = dss.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Service").ToString()
```

Also avoid to use string concatenation for sql command texts, use always a parameterized query

```
Private Sub cbxserviceid_SelectedIndexChanged(......)
    Dim dss As New DataSet
    if cbxserviceid.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim daa As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * from service_details WHERE ServiceID=@id", _
                                        objconnection)
        daa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",  Convert.ToInt32(cbxserviceid.Text))
        daa.Fill(dss)
        txtService1.Text = dss.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Service").ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```

I have also removed the creation of the MySqlCommandBuilder, being the adapter a local variable it has no sense or effect (if this is all your code in this event of course).

Looking at the comments below and the chat with the poster there is also another error to fix.
When assign a DataSource, DisplayMember and ValueMember property of a combobox it is mandatory to follow a precise order to avoid unwanted side effects

```
cbxserviceid.DisplayMember = "ServiceID"
cbxserviceid.ValueMember = "ServiceID"
cbxserviceid.DataSource = datatable
```

Comment: I am getting error Fatal error encountered during command execution.

 at `daa.fill(dss)` ?

Comment: Sorry I haven't noticed your first comment. Is the field ServiceID a string (text) in MySql or is an integer?

Comment: TinyInt (Auto increment)

Comment: Then we need to convert the parameter value to an integer (or short), updated the answer. If possible try also Convert.ToInt16

Comment: I now get Input string was not in a correct format on `daa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(cbxserviceid.Text))` Input16 throws same error

Comment: But what is the value of the cbxserviceid.Text? It should be a number.

Comment: It is single digit numbers, the value of the textbox which we're trying to populate is text

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47605/discussion-between-steve-and-livaren)