# Populating Textboxes and other fields with SQL Server data from multiple tables after a combobox item selection

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox

I am writing code to load & fill textboxes and other fields with data from multiple SQL Server tables after selected Index from Combobox!
the rest I figured out, But while running my project it gives error: "Column 's.staff_fullname' does not belong to table Table". Although I used JOINS but still no +ve result.

I got some help from this answer but still it is incomplete with regards to my question:

[Populate a textbox with mysql data after a combobox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809460/populate-a-textbox-with-mysql-data-after-a-combobox-selection)

here is the code I have written so far:

```
Private Sub cboISBN_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboISBN.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    If (cboISBN.SelectedIndex <> -1) Then
        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT s.staff_fullname, p.pub_name, " _
                                & " b.sub_code, b.isbn, b.book_name, " _
                                & " b.author, b.price, b.rack_no, " _
                                & " b.no_of_books, pby.vol_no, " _
                                & " pby.pub_date FROM book b JOIN published_by pby " _
                                & " ON b.isbn = pby.isbn JOIN publisher p on p.pub_id = b.pub_id " _
                                & " JOIN staff s ON s.staff_id = b.staff_id WHERE b.isbn =@isbn", cn)
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isbn", Convert.ToDecimal(cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString()))
        da.Fill(ds)
        cboStaff_id.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("s.staff_fullname").ToString()
        cboPub_id.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("p.pub_name").ToString()
        cboSub_Code.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("b.sub_code")
        txtbook_name.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("b.book_name").ToString()
        txtauthor.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("b.author").ToString()
        txtprice.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("b.price")
        txtrack_no.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("b.rack_no")
        TxtNo_of_Books.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("b.no_of_books")
        txtvol_no.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("pby.vol_no")
        DateTimePicker1.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("pby.pub_date")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question but since you are not using a stored procedure you should be careful using AddWithValue. It can sometimes get the datatype wrong with this type of parameterized pass through query. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @SeanLange I am getting this STORED PROCEDURE concern every where! can you provide me a good source to learn this quickly?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this stored procedure concern?

Comment: @SeanLange I studied stored procedures topic long time ago in College, but now I don't remember it! So I was asking you if you could provide me link or something to study stored procedure!

Comment: You really should learn how to use a search engine and find references in books online (BOL). It is the documentation for sql server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx

Comment: You should know that if your data model is flawed you will have lots of trouble going forward.  For instance, published_by as well as publisher tables seems...arbitrary.  Eventually a bad model can prevent the JOINs needed to get the data you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because of how you are referencing the results of your query.

```
cboStaff_id.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("s.staff_fullname").ToString()
```

You need to reference the column name in your dataset which is NOT the same as the alias in your query.

```
cboStaff_id.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("staff_fullname").ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I suggest you should simplify your code (and avoid possible performance issues if a form is large) by defining variable for a row:

```
Dim iRow as DataRow = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)
```

This way, you can reference the fields this way:

```
iRow("s.staff_fullname")
```

Once you introduce some IsDBNull() or other checking of input data, your old code will be unreadeable.

As for "Column 's.staff_fullname' does not belong to table Table", I think that it would say for a different column as well, if you change order of the lines which set the textboxes. I believe you need to use **result names**, which have never the table alias.
So instead of

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("s.staff_fullname").ToString()
```

try

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("staff_fullname")
```

If your column names colide (i.e. b.book_name with c.book_name) use alias within the SQL, i.e.:

```
b.book_name AS b_book_name, c.book_name AS c_book_name
```

Then you can use

```
ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("b_book_name")
```

or if you take my advice above, simply

```
iRow("b_book_name")
```

By the way, you shouldn't need the .ToString() function.

Oh, and one more hint: Why are you using a parameter, if you run the SQL code directly? You can simply Write it this way:

```
Dim CmdText as String = "SELECT s.staff_fullname, p.pub_name, " _
        & " b.sub_code, b.isbn, b.book_name, " _
        & " b.author, b.price, b.rack_no, " _
        & " b.no_of_books, pby.vol_no, " _
        & " pby.pub_date FROM book b JOIN published_by pby " _
        & " ON b.isbn = pby.isbn JOIN publisher p on p.pub_id = b.pub_id " _
        & " JOIN staff s ON s.staff_id = b.staff_id WHERE b.isbn = '" & _
        Convert.ToDecimal(cboISBN.SelectedValue.ToString()) & "'; "
```

*Note: This vb.net and SQL combination of code is not optimal. A Data Access Layer (a separate class with data access functions) is adviceable. Or alternatively usage of Stored Prodcedures; in this case variables must be provided as parameters.*

No need to use parameter at all...
And from here I can ask: Why are you converting value to string and then back to number?? And in particular decimal?? How's the ISBN a decimal number???

Regards,

Oak

Comment: I understand your comment about a parameter in this particular instance but honestly, suggesting that somebody not use a parameter is just irrational at best. Why wouldn't this be in a stored procedure instead of having the code in the application in the first place?

Comment: The code above is a VB.NET Sub and if one writes such a Sub it doesn't make sense to use parameter. It does no harm either, but I just wanted to show him a simple way.

Comment: Sure but if somebody comes along and decides to copy this code as an example and it isn't parameterized....

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're right, I didn't think of that. I'll add a comment.